# Serialize to ASP.NET ViewState using DataContract/DataMember attributes of EF POCOs

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, serialization, webforms, poco

I have a series of EF POCOs which have `DataContract` attributes, and **`DataMember` attributes** for all the properties, **except for the navigation properties**.

In this way, when I serialize the objects for WCF, only the desired properties are serialized, leaving out the navigation properties.

If I try to store one of these objects in ViewState I get the error that the object is not serializable. But, if I add the `Serializable` attribute to the object, the serializer tries to serialize also all the navigation properties, which, in turn requires them to be marked also as serializable.

Is there a way to force the `ViewState` (`StateBag`) to use the `DataContract` attributes? Is it possible to customize or replace the `ViewState` serialization?

If it's not possible, would I have to used the `Selializable` attribute for the classes, and the `NotSerialized` for all the navigation properties or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is a better solution - not to mix domains. When you serialize objects for WCF you are entering a different domain - the domain of Data Transfer Objects, DTOs in short.

DTOs are separate from your persisting objects, they don't have complex navigation properties, rather - contain the only data needed at the client side.

A commin practice is to use Automapper or a similar subsystem to easily convert from/to DTOs.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I usually use ValueInjecter. In this case I have a hybrid WebForms - MVC - WCF, and I have models for MVC (DTOs for this case). However I don't want to maintian extra classes for the WebForms part (which is being slowly removed from the app). At this point, I'm using a T4 template which generates all the classes from the DB... and I'm afraid I'll have to extend it to generate the classes needed for WebForms, and map them to EF POCOs, or add the missing Serializable/NotSerialized attributes (but I don't know what will happen if I mix DataContrat/DataMember with them).